# Split list into chunks with repeats between chunks

Tags: python

I have an array of elements, for example `r = np.arange(15)`.
I'm trying to split this array into chunks of consecutive elements, where each chunk (except maybe the last one) has size `M` and there are `m` repeating elements between each pair of chunks.

For example: `split_to_chunks(np.arange(15), M=5, m=1)` should yield four lists:
`[0, 1, 2, 3, 4]`, `[4, 5, 6, 7, 8]`, `[8, 9, 10, 11, 12]`, `[12, 13, 14]`

Obviously this can be done iteratively, but I'm looking for a more "pythonic" (and faster) way of doing this.

Comment: are you handling lists, or numpy arrays?

Comment: lists, numpy arrays, pandas Series - this should work for Iterables in general

Comment: Iteration is pythonic!!

Comment: `M=5; m=1; b=M-m; [a[i:i+M] for i in range(0,len(a),b)]`

Comment: Please check [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72293183) it works with different overlaps.

Comment: when you're right you're right

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this with list comprehension:

```
[l[i*(M-m):i*(M-m)+M] for i in range(math.ceil((len(l)-m)/(M-m)))]
```

**Example:**

```
import math
l = list(range(15))
# [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14]
m, M = 2, 5
[l[i*(M-m):i*(M-m)+M] for i in range(math.ceil((len(l)-m)/(M-m)))]
# [[0, 1, 2, 3, 4],
# [3, 4, 5, 6, 7],
# [6, 7, 8, 9, 10],
# [9, 10, 11, 12, 13],
# [12, 13, 14]]

m, M = 3, 5
[l[i*(M-m):i*(M-m)+M] for i in range(math.ceil((len(l)-m)/(M-m)))]
# [[0, 1, 2, 3, 4],
#  [2, 3, 4, 5, 6],
#  [4, 5, 6, 7, 8],
#  [6, 7, 8, 9, 10],
#  [8, 9, 10, 11, 12],
#  [10, 11, 12, 13, 14]]

l = range(5)
m, M = 2, 3
[l[i*(M-m):i*(M-m)+M] for i in range(math.ceil((len(l)-m)/(M-m)))]
# [range(0, 3), range(1, 4), range(2, 5)]
```

**Explanation:**

Chunk `i` starts at index `i*(M-m)` and ends M positions later at index `i*(M-m) + M`.

```
chunk index    starts           ends
-------------------------------------------------
0              0                M
1              M-m              M-m+M = 2*M-m
2              2*M-m-m=2(M-m)   2*(M-m)+M = 3M-2m
...
```

Now the problem is to determine how many chunks.

At each step we increase the initial index by `M-m`, so to count the total number of steps we need to divide the length of the list by `M-m` (but after subtracting `m` because in the first chunk we're not skipping anything).

Finally, use the ceiling function to add the last incomplete chunk in case the division is not exact.

Answer (score 1):

This should do the job:

```py
def split_to_chunks(r, M=5, m=1):
    return [r[i*(M-m): (i+1)*M-i*m] for i in range(len(r)//(M-m)+1) if i*(M-m) < len(r)]
```

Explanation: in a list comprehension loop through the indexes in the way explained in the question. Each start of a chunk will start at `i*(M-m)` and end at `(i+1)*M-i*m`. Finally if the start of the chunk is after the length of the array it will skip it.

Comment: Please add explanation to your answer

Comment: thanks! I think the `if` statement is redundant, no?

Comment: @JonNir in some cases you will have an empty list at the end if it is not there

Comment: This will give an incorrect result for for instance `split_to_chunks(np.arange(15), 5, 3)`